# How do I move a github branch from a repo into another repo in a different github organisation?

Tags: git, github

My company recently setup a new github organisation and want us to move our github repos from old organisation into the new one. One of my repo's main branch was cloned over, but I was still actively working on a personal branch in the old organisation. So, currently, I have

```
New Org -> New Repo -> Main Branch 
Old Org -> Old Repo -> Main + Personal Branch
```

I want to move the personal branch into the new org as well. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should:

```bash
# Clone OLD repo
git clone {{OLD_REPO_URL}} old_repo

# Enter OLD repo
cd old_repo

# Add a remote reference to the NEW repo
git remote add new_repo_origin {{NEW_REPO_URL}}

# Switch to your personal branch
git checkout {{MY_BRANCH}}

# Track and Push your personal branch to the NEW repo
git push -u new_repo_origin {{NEW_REPO_URL}}
```

**NB:** remember that the master history must be the same on the two, old and new, repositories.

Comment: I think you can cut down this recipe to just the `git remote add` and `git push` commands. You don't have to make a new clone.

Comment: The clone instruction has been only to clarify the fact that he should work on the OLD repo.